# Angular version mismatch on ng serve

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-devkit

This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^13.0.0,
but Angular version 12.2.13 was found instead.

Please visit the link below to find instructions on how to update Angular.
https://update.angular.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove current angular cli and install your supported version with

```
npm i -g @angular/cli@12.0.0
```

or you can follow that link and find out upgrade information for your current project

Comment: thank you...I tried with the different @angular-devkit/build-angular versions 12 -13..and also tried with angular/cli@12.0.0 but still getting the same...